# Hibernate HQL error

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm trying to write a HQL query as below

```
@query("SELECT a FROM Ac a join a.map m join m.Wall w  where a.Ac = m.Id and w.wall = :wall")
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
 org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Wall of:
```

Comment: Share the whole code of the `Map` and `Wall` entity.

Comment: You have m.Wall and w.wall, wall with first letter upper case and the other is lower. is that ok?